# Redirect stdin on popen subprocess to raw_input ? for python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

How do I redirect stdin in `subprocess.Popen` to raw input? I have tried to create a `Class` which inherits `File` class, but it says: `read attribute is 'read only'`.

**My Code:**

```
def read4(self,x):
    x=raw_input('=>')
    return x

def process(cmd):
    cmd=cmd.strip().split(' ')
    px.os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"

    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdin=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    process.stdin.read=read4

    return process

def output(process):
    while True:
        if stop:
            subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /F /PID {pid} /T".format(pid=process.pid))
            break
        out = process.stdout.read(1)

        if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
            break
        if out != '':
            yield out
            #sys.stdout.write(out)
            #sys.stdout.flush()

    p=process('python hello.py')
    for z in output(p):
       print z

    hello.py
    print 'hello'
    x=raw_input('enter: ')
    print x
```

Comment: I see you have `self` in `read4` but where is the class that you created?

Comment: Please check the formatting of your question. Also, make sure you don't have irrelevant stuff in your question (extract a [mcve]) that is not required to demonstrate the issue. In case you haven't already, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You *can't*. Quoting from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` specify the executed program’s standard
>   input, standard output and standard error **file handles**, respectively.
>   **Valid values are `PIPE`, an existing file descriptor (a positive
>   integer), an existing file object, and `None`.**

So you cannot use a function or a random object for `stdin`. You can simply let the subprocess use your current process stdin but there is no built-in way to automatically display the prompt before every line of input.

You could however manually do this by using `PIPE`. Read from your parent process stdin one line of input and then write it to the subprocess stdin & repeat.